# Download a file from a Nextcloud public link (pointing to a folder!) via command-line

Tags: nextcloud

Downloading a file from a Nextcloud **public link** via the webbrowser for sure is easy and a no brainer. The **link points to a folder** containing subfolders and files. Navigate to the desired folder an file and click it.

But how to accomplish to download /Subfolder1/Subfolder2/file1.exe from this public link via command-line? I searched for half an hour now but could not find a solution to this.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to download a file from a Nextcloud public link via the command line.

One way to do this is to use the curl command-line tool. Here is an example command that downloads a file from a Nextcloud public link:

```
curl -LJO "https://example.com/nextcloud/public.php?service=files&t=1234567890abcdefg&download&path=%2FSubfolder1%2FSubfolder2%2Ffile1.exe"
```

Replace `https://example.com/nextcloud/` with the URL of your Nextcloud instance, and replace `1234567890abcdefg` with the file's timestamp. You can find the timestamp in the public link URL after the `t=` parameter. Also, make sure to encode the path to the file in the link using URL encoding.

The `-L` option tells curl to follow any redirects that the server sends, and the `-O` option tells curl to write the output to a file with the same name as the remote file.

Comment: Thank you, but the answer does not exactly match my problem, as the public link points to a FOLDER, not to a file itself. So I've no timestamp or similar available. Also the file itself can change due to a newer version of it getting uploaded. The download should get the current version of the file present in the folder, regardless of it's version.

Answer (score 0):

We assume a password-protected share link such as `https://nc.example.com/s/SHARE_ID`.

### Show files in the shared folder:

```xml
$ curl -u SHARE_ID:SHARE_PASSWORD \
>    -X PROPFIND https://nc.example.com/public.php/webdav/
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<d:multistatus xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:s="http://sabredav.org/ns" xmlns:oc="http://owncloud.org/ns" xmlns:nc="http://nextcloud.org/ns">
  <d:response>
    <d:href>/public.php/webdav/</d:href>
    <d:propstat>
      <d:prop>
        <d:getlastmodified>Mon, 13 Nov 2023 08:49:15 GMT</d:getlastmodified>
        <d:resourcetype>
          <d:collection/>
        </d:resourcetype>
        <d:quota-used-bytes>24</d:quota-used-bytes>
        <d:quota-available-bytes>-3</d:quota-available-bytes>
        <d:getetag>"6551e30b2a978"</d:getetag>
      </d:prop>
      <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
    </d:propstat>
  </d:response>
  <d:response>
    <d:href>/public.php/webdav/anotherfolder/</d:href>
    <d:propstat>
      <d:prop>
        <d:getlastmodified>Mon, 13 Nov 2023 08:48:22 GMT</d:getlastmodified>
        <d:resourcetype>
          <d:collection/>
        </d:resourcetype>
        <d:quota-used-bytes>17</d:quota-used-bytes>
        <d:quota-available-bytes>-3</d:quota-available-bytes>
        <d:getetag>"6551e30b2a978"</d:getetag>
      </d:prop>
      <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
    </d:propstat>
  </d:response>
  <d:response>
    <d:href>/public.php/webdav/test.txt</d:href>
    <d:propstat>
      <d:prop>
        <d:getlastmodified>Mon, 13 Nov 2023 08:01:19 GMT</d:getlastmodified>
        <d:getcontentlength>7</d:getcontentlength>
        <d:resourcetype/>
        <d:getetag>"fb88afcb16622bcf16caa96dbfc9a57b"</d:getetag>
        <d:getcontenttype>text/plain</d:getcontenttype>
      </d:prop>
      <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
    </d:propstat>
  </d:response>
</d:multistatus>
```

(You can pretty print the XML response by adding `-o >(xmllint --format -)` to the `curl` command.)

Note this only shows files in the provided directory. To see the contents of the nested directory (in this example named `anotherfolder`), you would use the URL `https://nc.example.com/public.php/webdav/anotherfolder`.

### Fetch a particular file from the password-protected share

```
$ curl -u SHARE_ID:SHARE_PASSWORD \
>    https://nc.example.com/public.php/webdav/test.txt
Hello, world!
```

### Fetch a particular file from a subdirectory:

```
$ curl -u SHARE_ID:SHARE_PASSWORD \
>     https://nc.example.com/public.php/webdav/anotherfolder/deep.txt
This is a nested file
```

### Caveats

- This has been tested on Nextcloud server version 26.0.x.
- If the share is not password-protected, you can leave out the `SHARE_PASSWORD` from the `curl` `-u` switch: `curl -u SHARE_ID: <URL>`.
- As an alternative, consider using a program such as `cadaver` that provides a (familiar) FTP interface to the WEBDAV API.

Answer (score -1):

ChatGPT gave me the solution: just add a `/download?path=xyz/&files=filename` to the public link.

Example:
https://yournextcloud.com/PUBLICLINK/download?path=Subfolder1/Subfolder2/&files=filename.exe

Comment: Please read Stack Overflow's policies on chatGPT content. https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy